# can i pass in IQueryable<Foo> into IQueryable<IFoo> if the object implements that interface?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

i have an object that is a:

```
IQueryable<Foo>
```

and i want to pass it into a function that expects a:

```
IQueryable<IFoo>
```

Foo DOES implements IFoo

why wouldn't this compile?  what is the best way to convert to have this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Co- and contra- variance were added in the .NET 4 BCL, and do not exist in the .NET 3.5 BCL.

You can work around this limitation in 3.5 by using the `Select` operation to cast to your interface type:

```
IQueryable<Foo> foos = ..;
myFunc(foos.Select(x => (IFoo)x));
```

**Edit** (from Reed's comment, below):

```
IQueryable<Foo> foos = ..;
myFunc(foos.Cast<IFoo>());
```

Comment: +1: I'd recommend using `foo.Cast<IFoo>()` instead, though: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301460.aspx

Comment: ...I wasn't aware `IQueryable` had a `Cast`! Good tip!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer by [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940644/can-i-pass-in-iqueryablefoo-into-iqueryableifoo-if-the-object-implements-that/4940658#4940658), you could also use the [OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344857.aspx) expression:

```
IQueryable<Foo> foos = GetFoos();
var ifoos = foos.OfType<IFoo>();
```

<s>I'd imagine the `OfType` method may be a bit faster since the expression is filters the collection by type rather than casting.</s>

Anthony Pegram made a good observation/point in the comments. Here's a quick test of `OfType<>` vs `Cast<>` on a collection of 1,000,000 items:

```
OfType Test
00:00:00.1034880
00:00:00.0966734
00:00:00.0969874
00:00:00.1318617
00:00:00.0984404
00:00:00.0970098
00:00:00.0981691
00:00:00.0972425
00:00:00.1330730
00:00:00.1239663
total: 00:00:01.0769116
  avg: 00:00:00.1076911

Cast Test
00:00:00.0556266
00:00:00.0729768
00:00:00.0512704
00:00:00.0519060
00:00:00.0533288
00:00:00.0752939
00:00:00.0754975
00:00:00.0821554
00:00:00.0536814
00:00:00.0754732
total: 00:00:00.6472100
  avg: 00:00:00.0647210
```

Comment: `OfType` will still cast to the desired type. Think of it as `if (obj is TResult) yield return (TResult)obj;` If the sequence is entirely of `TResult`, then the check is superfluous. Think of `Cast` as simply `yield return (TResult)obj;` Which do you think will be faster? Use `OfType` when the source sequence is truly mixed. Use `Cast` when it is not.

Comment: Another (and perhaps more important) reason to use `Cast` in many cases is the explicitness implied. It would be an exceptional condition if something was in the sequence that you did not expect. `OfType` would obviously not miss a beat. Is your program correct? Depends. Did or did you not expect that everything in the sequence was convertible to a given type?

Comment: @Anthony - good clarification and explanation. The intent is a good point, i.e., am I wanting to filter on a type? or just cast everything?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why that doesn't work is because `List<Foo>` is a new class being generated and so is `List<IFoo>`... so, by the time the compiler is done with them, their will now be 2 totally new and unique classes in your project.

EDIT: A sort-of-solution:

What you can do is this:

```
var myIFooList = myFooList.Select(item => (IFoo)item).ToList();
```

Comment: Heh, this answer makes a lot more sense now that you can see the &lt; tag.

Comment: Use the backtick `\`` around `List<Foo>` to improve inline code readability, particularly when generics are involved.